# Attempting to nest several frames within a single frame with Tkinter. How do I accomplish this in an object oriented fashion?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-layout

My code basically does this:

[image: my problem]

Which is clearly not what I want to try. For further clarification I would like my window to look similar to this:

[image: an ideal solution]

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk()

class Encoding(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)
        self.mode = StringVar()
##      If I remove the next line it breaks it entirely.
        self.encoding_frame = ttk.Frame(parent)
        self.encrypt = ttk.Radiobutton(self.encoding_frame, text='Encrypt', variable=self.mode, value='encrypt')
        self.decrypt = ttk.Radiobutton(self.encoding_frame, text='Decrypt', variable=self.mode, value='decrypt')
        self.encrypt.grid(column=0, row=0, ipadx=2, sticky=W)
        self.decrypt.grid(column=0, row=1, ipadx=2, sticky=W)
        self.encoding_frame.grid(column=0, columnspan=3, row=2, sticky=S)


class MainApplication(tk.Frame, Encoding):
    # Create a main frame here.
    # Would like frames to be nested within this frame. This seems redundant but nesting with a main
    # frame allows for consistent themes, and gives additional control of layout between subframes.
    # Inheritance is confusing.
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)
        self.main_frame = ttk.LabelFrame(parent, text="Main Window", width=500, height=500)
        self.main_frame['borderwidth'] = 3
        self.main_frame['relief'] = 'raised'
        self.main_frame.grid(column=0, row=0)
        self.encoding = Encoding(self)
##      I wrote the following line hoping that I could have main_frame become the parent frame.
        self.encoding.encoding_frame = ttk.LabelFrame(self.main_frame)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = MainApplication(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

I am clearly not getting something right. The whole reason I rewrote the program is so that I could gain a greater understanding/confidence with object oriented code. I am hoping that I can get better insight with this, so any help would be amazing.

Comment: ***"# Inheritance is confusing."***: Avoid `multiple inheritance`, you didn't `Encoding.__init__(...`. Read [Why are multiple instances of Tk discouraged?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48045401/why-are-multiple-instances-of-tk-discouraged)

Comment: Why would I avoid multiple inheritance?

Also, I'm not sure that I did create multiple instances of Tk? I'm afraid that your comment is a bit confusing. Could you be more specific?

Comment: It is not multiple inheritance should be avoided. Rather, the widgets of tkinter are already inheriting from common base class `Widget`, which also inherits from multiple classes like `BaseWidget`, `Pack`... it complicates your code unnecessarily if you try to mix it up further.

Comment: Also regarding multiple instances, in your code `root = tk.Tk()` create one instance of `Tk`. Then, your `Encoding` class inherits from `tk.Tk`, which also creates another instance of `Tk` when you call it `MainApplication`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are are several problems going on with your code.

Perhaps the biggest problem is that `Encoding` inherits from `tk.Tk`, `MainApplication` inherits from `tk.Frame` *and* `Encoding` (making it both a root window and a frame), and then `MainApplication` creates an instance of `Encoding`. Plus, you explicitly create another instance of `tk.Tk()`, giving you two root windows. That all needs to be untangled.

Inheritance create a *"is a"* relationship. By having `MainApplication` inherit from `Encoding` you are saying that `MainApplication` is a `Encoding` object. That is not the case in your code - an `Encoding` object represents only a small part of the application. For that you want *composition*, not *inheritance*, ie: `MainApplication` *has a* `Encoding` object.

So, the first step is to remove `Encoding` from the list of classes that `MainApplication` inherits from.

Another thing that can probably be removed is `self.encoding_frame`. I see no reason to have it since `MainApplication` itself is a frame. Instead, have `MainApplication` inherit from `ttk.LabelFrame` rather than `tk.Frame`.

The final thing is that since `MainApplication` creates `Encoding`, it should be responsible for calling `grid` or `pack` on the instance of `Encoding`.

Altogether, `MainApplication` can be pared down to this:

```
class MainApplication(ttk.LabelFrame):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        ttk.LabelFrame.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)

        self.configure(text="Main Window")
        self['borderwidth'] = 3
        self['relief'] = 'raised'

        self.encoding = Encoding(self)
        self.encoding.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="ew")
```

That's not 100% complete, but it's a good place to start. Based on your image I'm guessing you'll have other classes for other parts of the main application -- the message widget, the key widgets, and the transcription window.

For `Encoding`, much of the same advice applies. Since it's only part of the application, it shouldn't inherit from `tk.Tk`. Instead, you can inherit from `ttk.Frame` and then remove `self.encoding_frame` since the `Encoding` object itself is already a frame.

With those changes, `Encoding` should look something like the following. Notice how the radiobuttons have `self` as their parent. If you're creating proper objects, all widgets inside the class need to be a child of the class itself or one of its descendants. A class like this should never put anything in `parent` except itself.

```
class Encoding(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        ttk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)

        self.mode = StringVar()
        self.encrypt = ttk.Radiobutton(self, text='Encrypt', variable=self.mode, value='encrypt')
        self.decrypt = ttk.Radiobutton(self, text='Decrypt', variable=self.mode, value='decrypt')

        self.encrypt.grid(column=0, row=0, ipadx=2, sticky=W)
        self.decrypt.grid(column=0, row=1, ipadx=2, sticky=W)
```

Finally, since `MainApplication` is now a frame -- instead of inheriting from `Encoding` which inherits from `tk.Tk` -- the block of code that creates an instance of `MainApplication` needs to be responsible for calling `pack` or `grid`. Since `MainApplication` is the only widget directly inside of the root window, `pack` is the best choice since you don't have to remember to configure row and column weights to get proper behavior when the window is resized.

Also, I recommend creating `root` in the same block rather than at the very start of the program.

Your bottom block of code should look like this:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = MainApplication(root)
    app.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: This is awesome, thank you so much!

I was actually attempting to follow your advice on another thread that was created called "Best way to structure a tkinter application?" but I was not doing a very good job, apparently. Was not expecting to get an answer directly from you! :D 

I was probably over thinking it, and I should have paired it down to the basics like you did. Thank you for your help.